# input text add a star with other color in placeholder

Tags: jquery, css

How can I add a star with other color in placeholder for `<input type="text" />` like this?
[image: placeholder with formatting]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/fuexebw7/

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add html formatting to a placeholder, but you could achieve what you are looking for with relatively position element (label) which has visibility settings bound to various interactions with the input. Essentially, when the text field is being modified or has a value, you hide the label, when it is empty, you show it.

Alternatively, you can use the example provided by coma to modify the placeholder with CSS, but that will not be cross-browser compatible.

Comment: hummm, yes you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css , obviously not that browser friendly wide.